# Finding greatest value in array smaller than x

Tags: java, algorithm, array, binary-search, mathematics

Code review requested to make this code simpler, cleaner, and better. Input array is sorted.

This program finds the greatest number smaller than `x`.  So, in an array `[10 20 30 40]` and `x = 25`, the output should be 20.

```
public class GreatestValueLesserThanEqualToX {

    public static Integer findGreatestValueLesserThanOrEqualToX (int[] arr, int x) {
        if (arr == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(" The input array is null. ");
        }
        if (arr.length >= 1) {
            return findGreatestValueLesserThanOrEqualToX (arr, x, 0, arr.length - 1);
        } else {
            return null;  // note the difference wrt greatest value lesser than X.
        }
    }

    private static Integer findGreatestValueLesserThanOrEqualToX (int[] arr, int x, int lb, int ub) {

        assert arr != null;

        final int mid = (lb + ub) / 2;

        /**
         *  Testing boundaries.
         */
        // testing lower boundary.
        if (mid == 0) {
            if (arr[mid] > x) {
                return null;
            }

            // single element array with value lesser than input value.
            if (arr.length == 1) {
                return arr[0];
            }
        }

        //testing higher boundary.
        if (lb == (arr.length - 1) && arr[mid] < x) {
            return arr[mid]; 
        }

        /**
         *  Testing equalities and duplicates.
         */
        // testing equality and duplicates. eg: consider input like: 1, 2, 2, 5
        if (arr[mid] == x || arr[mid + 1] == x) {
            return x;
        }

        /**
         *  Testing when element is in the range of array elements.
         */
        // input x in range of array elements.
        if (arr[mid] < x && arr[mid + 1] > x) {
             return arr[mid]; // note the difference wrt greatest value lesser than X.
         }

         if (arr[mid] < x) {
             return findGreatestValueLesserThanOrEqualToX (arr, x, mid + 1, ub);
         } else {
             return findGreatestValueLesserThanOrEqualToX (arr, x, lb, mid);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Interface Design

The class could be better named.  (As @DaveJarvis points out, it's more of a namespace than a class, but I'm OK with a design that is not pure OOP.)  I suggest `BinarySearcher`: it describes what it can do, without repeating the name of the function, and still leaves it open for you to add a `findSmallestValueGreaterThanOrEqualToX()` function later.

Returning an `Integer` is weird, especially since the inputs are unboxed `int`s.  I know, you want to be able to return `null` if no suitable element is found.  I have another suggestion: return the *index* of the element found rather than the element itself; if no suitable element exists then return -1.  That behaviour is reminiscent of `String.indexOf()`, which all Java programmers should be familiar with.  Knowing the index, the caller can easily retrieve the element from the array.

We could also shorten the function name a bit.  I suggest that the method signature should be

```
/**
 * Given a sorted array and a limit, finds the rightmost element
 * whose value does not exceed the limit.
 *
 * @param data An array sorted in ascending order
 * @param limit The maximum value to look for
 * @return The index of the last element in data whose value is less
 *         than or equal to limit.  If no such element exists, returns -1.
 */
public static int greatestIndexNotExceeding(int[] data, int limit)
```

## Search Logic

There is no reason for your helper function to consult `arr.length`.  The helper function's job is to look between indices `lb` and `ub`.  The caller will vouch for the validity of those bounds.  What happens beyond that range is none of the helper function's business.

You have *seven* cases, which is way too many.  You should only need four:

- No suitable element
- Found the result
- Consider the upper half of the range
- Consider the lower half of the range

## Null-Handling

There's no need to `throw new NullPointerException()` explicitly.  The very next line will raise a `NullPointerException` naturally when it tries to access `arr.length`.  The `arr != null` assertion is similarly pointless.

When might it be beneficial to check for `null` explicitly?  When a constructor or a setter method accepts an argument and stores it for future use, but does not try to use it immediately.  In those cases, it can be hard to track down later how an instance or class variable came to be `null`.

---

## Proposed Solution

```
public class BinarySearcher {
    /**
     * Insert JavaDoc here…
     */
    public static int greatestIndexNotExceeding(int[] data, int limit) {
        if (data.length < 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        return greatestIndexNotExceeding(data, limit, 0, data.length - 1);
    }

    private static int greatestIndexNotExceeding(int[] data, int limit, int lb, int ub) {
        final int mid = (lb + ub) / 2;

        // Need to go lower but can't
        if (mid == lb && data[mid] > limit) {
            return -1;
        }

        // Found a candidate, and can't go higher
        if (data[mid] <= limit && (mid == ub || data[mid + 1] > limit)) {
            return mid;
        }

        if (data[mid] <= limit) {
            // Consider upper half
            return greatestIndexNotExceeding(data, limit, mid + 1, ub);
        } else {
            // Consider lower half
            return greatestIndexNotExceeding(data, limit, lb, mid);
        }
    }
}
```

It should be possible to restructure the code to reduce the number of comparisons between `data[mid]` and `limit`, but I think it's more readable this way.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a class: it is a collection of functions. A class has attributes (instance variables) and behaviours (methods that perform operations on the data):

> A class is a software element describing an abstract data type and its partial or total implementation. An abstract data type is a set of objects defined by the list of **operations**, or *features*, applicable to these objects, and the **properties** of these operations.
>
> ~ Bertrand Meyer, [Object-Oriented Software Construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction), 2nd Edition, p.23.

Consider:

```
/**
 * Allows clients to determine the first value that matches
 * a list of values, based on a particular comparator.
 */
public class Determinator {
    private int[] list = new int[0];
    private Comparator comparator;

    public Determinator( int[] list ) {
      this( list, new LessThanComparator() );
    }

    public Determinator( int[] list, Comparator comparator ) {
      setList( list );
      setComparator( comparator );
    }

    private void setList( int[] list ) {
      if( list != null ) {
        this.list = list;
      }
    }

    private void setComparator( Comparator comparator ) {
      // Same as setList...
    }

    /**
     * Finds the first value in the list that has the relationship
     * to x as denoted by the comparator option.
     *
     * @param x The value to compare against the list of values.
     * @throws InvalidParameterException There was no valid value to return.
     */
    public int findValue( int x ) throws InvalidParameterException {
    }

    public boolean isWithinBoundary( ... ) {
    }

    public boolean isDuplicate( ... ) {
    }

    public boolean isInRange( ... ) {
    }
}
```

Note:

- All assertions and tests for `null` values are no longer necessary.
- The interface (i.e., method definitions) for how the class works can be written independently of the methods themselves.
- Using a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object makes the code more generic, as it can perform any number of comparisons beyond less-than-or-equal-to.
- The logic has been separated into smaller, more manageable methods.
- No `null` values are returned: an exception is thrown when a suitable value is not found.

Comment: Please explain the downvotes so that we all can learn.

Comment: No idea what the downvote was for, since this is a useful answer.  +1.  Some critiques, though: 1) if you use `Comparator`, you should explicitly assign the generic type `<T>`; 2) a constructor with *less* arguments should always refer to a constructor with *more* arguments, not the other way around; 3) throwing an `Exception` if no value is found is a bad approach - Exceptions should be used for errors, not for control flow; 4) Saying "That is not a class" may be misleading to new Java developers.  It *is* a class, just one that only has `static` methods and would be useless to instantiate.

Comment: Upon further thought, the Exception throwing might not be that bad, depending on the use of this API and how "low-level" you intend it to be.  It's a serious design consideration, though.

Comment: Haha, I'd never read the "Hoare's billion dollar mistake" quote.  Very nice.

Comment: 1) Agreed. 2) Fixed. 3) Disagree (see Hoare's billion dollar mistake). 4) Disagree; see update.

Comment: To clarify, I disagree that the exception represents a control flow. I *agree* that exceptions should not be used for control flow because that violates the principle of least astonishment. There is nothing astonishing about a documented exception thrown for an *exceptional* scenario. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/729404/59087

Comment: A static function solves this problem just fine. A `Discriminator` class might be a good idea in some circumstances. However, the problem could be generalized in a number of different directions; in the absence of any particular need, I would do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work.

Comment: @200_success: If someone requests a code review using an OO language, then the code should leverage object-oriented techniques (as simply as possible). Otherwise, *The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work* would be to write it in a non-OO language, and eschew the benefits of object-orientation.